# Counting non-contiguous values

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have the following structure:

```
+------+---------------+---------------+----+
| guid | current_level | current_value | pk |
+------+---------------+---------------+----+
| a    |           100 |            12 |  1 |
| a    |           200 |            12 |  2 |
| a    |           200 |            12 |  3 |
| a    |           200 |            12 |  4 |
| a    |           200 |            12 |  6 |
| a    |           300 |            14 |  7 |
| a    |           300 |            12 |  9 |
| a    |           300 |            12 | 10 |
| a    |           300 |            14 | 12 |
| b    |           100 |            10 |  5 |
| b    |           100 |            10 |  8 |
| b    |           200 |            12 | 11 |
| b    |           200 |            12 | 13 |
+------+---------------+---------------+----+
```

I wish to count the number of times a and b went to level 200 non-contiguously (and 300 but just 200 for now)
i.e the result I'm expecting:

```
+------+-------+-------+
| guid | level | times |
+------+-------+-------+
| a    |   200 |     1 |
| b    |   200 |     1 |
+------+-------+-------+
```

(I can't just do unique because separate streaks of 200s should be counted separately)

When I do the following:

```
set @id = "none";
set @lev = 10; -- arbitary non zero starting level

SELECT  guid, current_level , if(@id <> guid, @lev := 10, 0) AS useless, case when @id <> guid then @id := guid else 0 end AS useless2
         , (case when (current_level = 200 AND current_level <> @lev) then 1 else 0 end) as TIMES
        , if(current_level = 200 AND current_level <> @lev, @lev := current_level, 0) AS useless3

 FROM (SELECT * FROM sensor_logs order by guid) as T
```

I get:

```
+------+---------------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| guid | current_level | useless | useless2 | TIMES    | useless3 |
+------+---------------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| a    |           100 |      10 | a        |        0 |        0 |
| a    |           200 |       0 | 0        |        1 |      200 |
| a    |           200 |       0 | 0        |        0 |        0 |
| a    |           200 |       0 | 0        |        0 |        0 |
| a    |           200 |       0 | 0        |        0 |        0 |
| a    |           300 |       0 | 0        |        0 |        0 |
| a    |           300 |       0 | 0        |        0 |        0 |
| a    |           300 |       0 | 0        |        0 |        0 |
| a    |           300 |       0 | 0        |        0 |        0 |
| b    |           100 |      10 | b        |        0 |        0 |
| b    |           100 |       0 | 0        |        0 |        0 |
| b    |           200 |       0 | 0        |        1 |      200 |
| b    |           200 |       0 | 0        |        0 |        0 |
+------+---------------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

So now summing the `TIMES` column and grouping by `guid` should do the trick, ie:

```
set @id = "none";
set @lev = 10; -- arbitary non zero starting level

SELECT  guid, current_level , if(@id <> guid, @lev := 10, 0) AS useless, case when @id <> guid then @id := guid else 0 end AS useless2
         , sum(case when (current_level = 200 AND current_level <> @lev) then 1 else 0 end) as TIMES
        , if(current_level = 200 AND current_level <> @lev, @lev := current_level, 0) AS useless3

 FROM (SELECT * FROM sensor_logs order by guid) as T
 GROUP BY guid
```

But I get the following:

```
+------+---------------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| guid | current_level | useless | useless2 | TIMES    | useless3 |
+------+---------------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| a    |           100 |      10 | a        |        4 |        0 |
| b    |           100 |      10 | b        |        2 |        0 |
+------+---------------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I do not understand why summing a column which had two 1s (one for each guid) results in 4 and 2.

Is it something I am doing wrong? or more to do with the underlying mechanics of how the query (and sum function) is executed?

Comment: it is clear that you are summing the ocurrences of 200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query you better write it like this:

```
SELECT  guid, current_level , if(@id <> guid, @lev := 10, 0) AS useless, case when @id <> guid then @id := guid else 0 end AS useless2
         , (case when (current_level = 200 AND current_level <> @lev) then 1 else 0 end) as TIMES
        , if(current_level = 200 AND current_level <> @lev, @lev := current_level, 0) AS useless3

 FROM sensor_logs
 , (SELECT @id := 'none', @lev := 10) var_init_subquery
 ORDER BY guid
```

Not only is it more clean to do the ordering explicitly when needed, not in a subquery, doing it in a subquery might also lead to a bad execution plan (which means bad performance in case of temporary table).

For your final result, you shouldn't directly apply the GROUP BY and so on. The SELECT (and therefore your variables and calculations) are evaluated **after** the GROUP BY. To do the grouping after your calculations, put your query in a subquery:

```
SELECT guid, SUM(times) FROM (
    SELECT  guid, current_level , if(@id <> guid, @lev := 10, 0) AS useless, case when @id <> guid then @id := guid else 0 end AS useless2
             , (case when (current_level = 200 AND current_level <> @lev) then 1 else 0 end) as TIMES
            , if(current_level = 200 AND current_level <> @lev, @lev := current_level, 0) AS useless3

     FROM sensor_logs
     , (SELECT @id := 'none', @lev := 10) var_init_subquery
     ORDER BY guid
) sq
GROUP BY guid
```

Comment: Thank you! works perfectly. From a performance standpoint where does this stand? (given a medium sized database)

Comment: Depends entirely on your machine. There's no filtering going on, so you'll do a full-table scan.

Comment: Given the problem is there a "smarter" way to go about this?

Comment: I don't think so.