# Optimized way to count non-contiguous sets of rows based on a column

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Original: [Counting non-contiguous values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44454384/counting-non-contiguous-values)

I'll change the structure a bit so its more obvious what I'm trying to do.

Given:

```
+------+---------------+---------------+----+
| guid | current_level | current_value | pk |
+------+---------------+---------------+----+
| a    |           100 |            12 |  1 |
| a    |           200 |            12 |  2 |
| a    |           200 |            12 |  3 |
| a    |           200 |            12 |  4 |
| a    |           300 |            14 |  7 |
| a    |           300 |            12 |  9 |
| a    |           200 |            14 | 12 |
| b    |           100 |            10 |  5 |
| b    |           100 |            10 |  8 |
| b    |           200 |            12 | 11 |
| b    |           100 |            12 | 13 |
| b    |           200 |            12 | 14 |
| b    |           300 |            12 | 15 |
| b    |           200 |            12 | 16 |
+------+---------------+---------------+----+
```

I want to count the total number of times each `guid` went into level 200, ignoring the rows where it stayed at 200. So consecutive rows of level 200 should be treated as 1, whereas a transition from 200 -> 100 (or 300) -> 200 would count as 2.

The result I'm looking for, given the above structure is:

```
+------+-------+-------+
| guid | level | times |
+------+-------+-------+
| a    |   200 |     2 |
| b    |   200 |     3 |
+------+-------+-------+
```

The original question (linked above) does work technically, however when the solution is used on a table with 1.8M rows it takes around 30 seconds which is less than optimal.

Note: The internal sub-query of the solution (sq) tends to take less than a second but the entire query performs poorly (I would appreciate if someone could explain why this could be, maybe because of the large size of the temp table?)

Question is what is an efficient way to accomplish what I am trying given the table size.

Old query for reference:

```
SELECT guid, SUM(TIMES) FROM (
    SELECT  guid, current_level ,
            if(@id <> guid, @lev := 10, 0) AS useless,
            if(@id <> guid, @id := guid, 0) AS useless2,
            (case when (current_level = 200
                    AND current_level <> @lev) then 1 else 0 end) as TIMES,
            if(current_level <> @lev, @lev := current_level, 0) AS useless3

     FROM sensor_logs
     , (SELECT @id := 'none', @lev := 10) var_init_subquery
     ORDER BY guid
) sq
GROUP BY guid
```

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned that performance is your concern here, trying any sort of select query is equally going to take time as the number of records increase.

In my mind, an approach would be

1. Create a trigger on the table for " after insert "
2. Based on the NEW.guid, find the last record and see if it is 200 or not
3. Maintain a separate table just with guid and the count
4. When last record is not 200, update the new table count for the guid (or insert if there is no record)

I feel overall, this will optimize the performance

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time one goes wrong when working with session variables in MySQL due to bad and untested syntax.  In the query below, we use two session variables.  The first one, `@current_level`, stores the lag of the current level value.  The `guid_no` variable stored the lag of the `guid_no`.  The logic for counting a matching row, then, is that we encounter a `200` value from a non `200` value *and* the `guid_no` has not changed.  Then, aggregate over this could by the `guid_no` to obtain the final result you want.

```
SET @current_level = NULL;
SET @guid_no = NULL;

SELECT
    t.guid,
    SUM(guid_sum) AS times
FROM
(
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN (@current_level <> 200 AND current_level = 200) AND (@guid_no = guid)
             THEN 1 END AS guid_sum,
        @current_level:=current_level,
        @guid_no:=guid AS guid,
        current_value,
        pk
    FROM sensor_logs
    ORDER BY guid, pk
) t
GROUP BY t.guid;
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

By the way, if you ever get stuck using session variables in MySQL to simulate row number functionality, here is a great reference which I find extremely helpful:

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/

Comment: Add on `INDEX(guid, pk)` for more speed.  See the `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` exists in MariaDB 10.2; see "windowing functions"